# How to only listen to one event at time and close other listeners in javascript>

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseevent

I have started to learn javascript.I have multiple functions currently attached to three different buttons which trigger a listener to table to select cells.For example if press button it trigger the assignsource  function.The problem arises when i try to click on another button such as select Destination to select a cell on table.However it also triggers the select source function which i donot want.I have used once property it solves the problem but it closes the listener after single click but i want to continue assigning sources on table

edit:i am trying to create a path finding visualizer.I have created a six by six grid which is a table actually.I place source on some cell and a destiniation on some ther cell.Then i run DFS or whatever algorithm.the problem arrises If i select the source button and place source but when i am done with it and try to place destination node by clicking on the destination button it also changes the source node since the source function is also listening
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEzt2.png)

```
function AssingSrcByClick() {

      console.log("ASSING SOURCE CALLED");
      const table = document.querySelector('table');
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
      const rowsArray = Array.from(rows);

      table.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          const rowIndex = rowsArray.findIndex(row => row.contains(event.target));
          const columns = Array.from(rowsArray[rowIndex].querySelectorAll('td'));
          const columnIndex = columns.findIndex(column => column == event.target);
          var r = rowIndex;
          var c = columnIndex;
          console.log(r, c)
          AssingSrc(r, c);

      }, {
          once:true
      })
      console.log(G);
  }

  function AssingWALLSByClick() {

      console.log("ASSIGN WALLS CALLED");
      const table = document.querySelector('table');
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
      const rowsArray = Array.from(rows);

      table.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          const rowIndex = rowsArray.findIndex(row => row.contains(event.target));
          const columns = Array.from(rowsArray[rowIndex].querySelectorAll('td'));
          const columnIndex = columns.findIndex(column => column == event.target);
          var r = rowIndex;
          var c = columnIndex;
          console.log(r, c)
          INITWALLS(r, c);
          console.log(G);
      }, {once: true})
  }

  function AssingDesByClick() {

      console.log("ASSIGN DES CALLED");
      const table = document.querySelector('table');
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
      const rowsArray = Array.from(rows);

      table.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          const rowIndex = rowsArray.findIndex(row => row.contains(event.target));
          const columns = Array.from(rowsArray[rowIndex].querySelectorAll('td'));
          const columnIndex = columns.findIndex(column => column == event.target);
          var r = rowIndex;
          var c = columnIndex;
          console.log(r, c)
          AssingDes(r, c);
          console.log(G);
      }, {
          once: true
      })
  }

  ;
  document.getElementById("PUTSOURCE").addEventListener("click", AssingSrcByClick);
  document.getElementById("PUTWALL").addEventListener("click", AssingWALLSByClick);
  document.getElementById("PUTDESTINATION").addEventListener("click", AssingDesByClick);
```

Comment: Adding event listeners inside another event listener is generally a bad practice that leads to problems such as the one you are having. It would help if you provided a higher level overview of the three functionalities expected here. This most likely can all be done in one table event listener and check the state of which button(s) have been selected within that event handler

Comment: @charlietfl i am trying to create a path finding visualizer.I have created a six by six grid which is a table actually.I place source on some cell and a destiniation on some ther cell.Then i run DFS or whatever algorithm.the problem arrises If  i select the source button and place  source but when i am done with it and try to place destination node by clicking on the destination button it also changes the source node since the source function is also listening

Comment: Ok. Well as I mentioned use button click events to track state of active button and then in a single table event listener use conditionals based on the button state

Comment: @charlietfl thanks man,ur idea worked.i have lot to learn about js

Comment: Glad it helped. There's a variety of approaches to track or check state of the buttons so add another question if you run into issues